# Problems with OneSignal wordpress plugin after moving website to https

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, onesignal

I moved a website to Https and got a problem with OneSignal push notification. I read the documentation of OneSignal but it doesn't help me. The website based on Wordpress and use OneSignal plugin. I received next error in Google dev tools:

***Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The path of the provided scope ('/') is not under the max scope allowed ('/wp-content/plugins/onesignal-free-web-push-notifications/sdk_files/'). Adjust the scope, move the Service Worker script, or use the Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP header to allow the scope.***

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem with it?

Comment: If you have an issue with a plugin, you should contact the plugin developers as they are in the best position to understand the problem and be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked to a lot of information and resources and found a problem. I use Incapsula as caching tool. This service blocked "Service-Worker-Allowed" header and that's why I got an error.